# BargainFinderMax returning NotFound - Sabre

Tags: rest, sabre

Environment - https://api.sabre.com/

Request Json:

```
    {
   "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ":{
      "DirectFlightsOnly":false,
      "AvailableFlightsOnly":false,
      "Version":"3.1.0",
      "Target":"Production",
      "POS":{
         "Source":[
            {
               "PseudoCityCode":"XXXX", //morphed for security
               "RequestorID":{
                  "Type":"1",
                  "ID":"1",
                  "CompanyName":{
                     "Code":"TN",
                     "content":"TN"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "OriginDestinationInformation":[
         {
            "RPH":"1",
            "DepartureDateTime":"2017-06-05T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation":{
               "LocationCode":"JFK"
            },
            "DestinationLocation":{
               "LocationCode":"LAX"
            },
            "TPA_Extensions":{
               "SegmentType":{
                  "Code":"O"
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "TravelPreferences":{
         "ValidInterlineTicket":true,
         "CabinPref":[
            {
               "Cabin":"Y",
               "PreferLevel":"Preferred"
            }
         ],
         "TPA_Extensions":{
            "TripType":{
               "Value":"OpenJaw"
            },
            "LongConnectTime":{
               "Min":1200,
               "Max":780,
               "Enable":true
            },
            "ExcludeCallDirectCarriers":{
               "Enabled":true
            }
         }
      },
      "TravelerInfoSummary":{
         "SpecificPTC_Indicator":true,
         "PriceRequestInformation":{
            "TPA_Extensions":{
               "PointOfSaleOverride":{
                  "Code":"TPE"
               }
            }
         },
         "SeatsRequested":[
            1
         ],
         "AirTravelerAvail":[
            {
               "PassengerTypeQuantity":[
                  {
                     "Code":"ADT",
                     "Quantity":1
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "TPA_Extensions":{
         "IntelliSellTransaction":{
            "RequestType":{
               "Name":"50ITINS"
            },
            "CompressResponse":{
               "Value":true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Response Json:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Conversation-ID: 
  Message-ID: mvwL2X
  X-Provider-Instance-ID: raf-darhlp019-9080
  Date: Thu, 25 May 2017 06:45:08 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 1159
  Content-Type: application/json
}}
```

The same request works with developer credentials but it is not working on production environment.

Comment: Do you have a BFM agreement for calling this service in PROD?

Comment: @Bruno yeah we do have

Comment: When you say that it works with developer credentials I'm guessing you are referring to the test key that is provided in DevStudio. Those won't work in PROD. If you have your own PCC, that's the one you should use to authenticate in PROD.

Comment: @Bruno i do have my own PCC and credentials, when i'm able to fetch the bargain finder max response using Developer credentials why I'm unable to fetch the bargain finder max response using my own PCC credentials? I'm using Rest method for fetching

Comment: You might need to report this to the helpdesk providing your credentials for further investigation.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno..

Answer (score -1):

**404 just means not found, so it is likely that this is as simple as using the wrong URL.**

Could it be that you are simply using the endpoint URL (https://api.sabre.com/) and not the complete one pointing to the actual service (v3.1.0/shop/flights).

To give you a better answer we need more information.